# Prevent clicking through div

Tags: css, html

I have a div container, which holds several "rows" of data, with each item in the list in it's own "listRow" div. I'm using jQuery to make the "listRow" divs selectable, by toggling the css styling when clicked. Also within each row is an image div that floats on the right side of it's parent "listRow" div and contains an onclick event. When I click on the image div, the onclick event fires, but the parent "listRow" div is also clicked and "selected".

How can I prevent from clicking through my image div?

pseudo html code:

```
<div class="listContainer">
    <div class="listRow" id="listRow1">
        <div class="listItemName">List item #1</div>
        <div class="listItemIcon"><img src="images/icon.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="listRow" id="listRow2">
        <div class="listItemName">List item #2</div>
        <div class="listItemIcon"><img src="images/icon.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("div.listRow").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
})
```

Comment: So you don't want the image to fire the click event?

Answer (score 29):

You'd use [**`event.stopPropagation()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

> `event.stopPropagation()` - Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM
>   tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

On the `div.listItemIcon`'s `click()` event to prevent the event bubbling:

```
$('div.listItemIcon').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("div.listRow").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

[**jsFiddle example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRwH7/)

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. I've got a button that sits on top of a div which works as an accordion. This stops the accordion function from happening when the element on top is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

In the click function of the image if you grab the event and use the `stopPropagation()` function then it should keep the event from firing the the element's parents. eg.

```
$('div.listItemIcon').click(function(e){
    //your code here
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a event parameter to the function and the following two return lines:

```
$("div.listRow").click(function(e){
    if (e.target != this)
        return;
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use 'event.stopImmediatePropagation()'

This saved my life! Hope it can save yours too 
Say you have a hidden modal (a simple `<div>` with `position: absolute` and `opacity: 0`) that is shown depending on user action.
The problem is that when clicking upon it, other elements "behind" the modal will also be triggered.
To prevent this behavior and avoid the click event to bubble up through the DOM (and touch other elements), **stopImmediatePropagation** is the prefect solution!

```
modal.addEventListener('click', e => {
    
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    
   //  click logic here ...
})
```

This way the event will only be listened for the very element where you have attached your eventListener.
In our example case the click will now act only upon the modal and won't touch underlying elements anymore.
And of course, it works not only for 'click' events but also for all kinds of user interaction events like 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'keydown', 'keyup' etc...

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the other solutions work, I've just discovered another alternative way of doing this!

If you want to block something from being clicked, you can position a disabled button on top of it. Something like this:

```
<div>you cannot click me because the disabled button will stop you</div>
<button disabled>you cannot click me or anything behind me</button>

button[disabled] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;      
}
```

The positioning and sizing of the button should be such that it blocks you from clicking the div.

I wouldn't use this on a regular basis, but its good to know. I found it useful when using Angular Material and whilst `evt.stopPropagation` nearly worked, it did not stop the mat ripple effect. But this approach did!

Comment: this looks like really bad semantics... instead of a button, you should rather give some div a class and put the css there, and if you want all clicks to land on the element instead of those underneat, add following CSS:  `pointer-events: all;`